# Getting started with XML::Parser

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

I've been googling for some time now in order to find information concerning the usage of a Perl-XML-Parser. Being quite a newbie, though, I couldn’t fully understand the documentation or the tutorials.

Just a few words about what I’d need the parser for (nothing exceptional, as you'll see):

I would like to read in an XML-file and transform it — in a first step — into a LaTeX-document. In a second step, I would like to extract certain pieces of information.

For example:

```
<body>
<head>Title</head>
<poem>
<l>xyz</l>
<l>xyz</l>
</poem>
</body>
```

This sample-"XML" should be transformed in something like:

```
\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\begin{verse}
xyz\\
xyz
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Furthermore, I would like to put certain pieces of information (e.g. the text between the `<l>...</l>`-tags) into an array/hash (perhaps together with the number of preceding `</l>`s)?.

I suppose, tasks like these can very easily be done with a parser. The problem is that I have got only a very vague idea of how to initialize and customize for ex. the XML::Parser module.

I'd be very thankful if anyone could help.

Comment: Are you tied to the expat perl Xml::Parser for any reason?  There are better and more standardized ways to parse xml that result in knowledge that is transferable outside of the perl world...

Comment: Have you tried [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Twig)? [Basic examples](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Twig#XML::Twig_101)

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility to handle XML in Perl is [XML::XSH2](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
use XML::XSH2;
xsh << 'end_xsh';
    open 8023786.xml ;
    cd body ;
    echo '\begin{document}' ;
    for poem {
        echo :s '\chapter{' preceding-sibling::head[1] '}' ;
        echo '\begin{verse}' ;
        for l echo :s text() xsh:if(following-sibling::*, '\\', '') ;
        echo '\end{verse}' ;
    }
    echo '\end{document}' ;
end_xsh
```

Comment: Kudos for using the mighty XML::XSH2 :D

Answer (score 1):

The "best" way to transform XML into Latex would be to use XSLT.

STRONG SUGGESTION:

1) Familiarize yourself with basic Perl XML.

Alternatively, use a different language if you feel more comfortable with something else besides Perl - there are good XML libraries available for most languages.

I'd strongly recommend working through all three chapters in this tutorial:

[XML For Perl Developers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xmlperl1/index.html)

2) Familiarize yourself with the basics of using XSLT stylesheets.  For example:

[Investigating XSLT: The XML Transformation Language](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/it/it-0801art14/)

3) Investigate some ready-made XML to Latex XSL stylesheets.  For example:

[XML to LaTeX](http://opera.inrialpes.fr/people/Tayeb.Lemlouma/MULTIMEDIA/XSLT/X2L.html)

... or ...

[Transforming XHTML to LaTeX](http://www.w3.org/2004/04/xhlt91/)

... or ...

[XSLT MathML Library](http://xsltml.sourceforge.net/)

PS:
I hasten to add that the XSLT approach is language- and platform-agnostic.  You can use this approach in any language (Perl, Java, Python, etc etc) and on any platform (Windows, Linux, MacOS, etc etc)

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyboy! I had a look at the various links and documentations you have recommended me. Since I have problems with understanding even the most basic documentations (although I am usually quite fine with perl and LaTeX documentations), I think it'll be the best solution just to get me a book and learn all the things I need to know from the scratch. Thanks again. Maybe I will need your advice in a couple of days again.

Answer (score 0):

For complete control over XML translation, implement a [finite-state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_machine) using [SAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML#XML_processing_with_SAX).
Perl has [XML::SAX](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSAX) with different parser backends ([XML::SAX::ExpatXS](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSAX%3a%3aExpatXS), [XML::LibXML::SAX](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aSAX)). Here is one possible solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
package XML::SAX::Handler::XML2LaTeX;
use feature qw(say switch);
use strict;
use warnings qw(all);

use base qw(XML::SAX::Base);

sub new {
    return bless {
        data => '',
        line => [],
    } => __PACKAGE__;
}

sub start_element {
    my ($self, $el) = @_;
    $self->{data} = '';
    for ($el->{Name}) {
        when ('body') {
            say '\begin{document}';
        } when ('poem') {
            say '\begin{verse}';
            $self->{line} = [];
        }
    }
    return;
}

sub end_element {
    my ($self, $el) = @_;
    my $data = $self->{data};
    for ($el->{Name}) {
        when ('body') {
            say '\end{document}';
        } when ('head') {
            say "\\chapter{$data}";
        } when ('poem') {
            say join "\\\\\n", @{$self->{line}};
            say '\end{verse}';
        } when ('l') {
            push @{$self->{line}}, $data;
        }
    }
    return;
}

sub characters {
    my ($self, $data) = @_;
    $self->{data} .= $data->{Data};
    return;
}

1;

package main;
use strict;
use warnings qw(all);

use XML::SAX::PurePerl;

my $handler = XML::SAX::Handler::XML2LaTeX->new;
my $parser = XML::SAX::PurePerl->new(Handler => $handler);

$parser->parse_file(\*DATA);

__DATA__
<body>
<head>Title</head>
<poem>
<l>xyz</l>
<l>xyz</l>
</poem>
</body>
```