# Perl - Modify the nested multi-register XML tags

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I have a complex multi-register document xml which I need to parse in Perl to output to different format.

input xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <response>
     <result name="response" numFound="58582" start="0"> 
     <doc>
        <str name="body">Have a great time at this park!</str><int name="is_park_id">317851</int><str name="ss_image_thumb_small"/>
    <str name="title">Playground</str>    
     </doc>
     <doc>
<str name="body">Have a great time at this park!</str><int name="is_park_id">317851</int><str name="ss_image_thumb_small"/>
    <str name="title">Playground</str>    
     </doc>
     </result>
     </response>
```

and the required output format is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
     <Feed>
     <Products>
     <Product>
<Description>Have a great time at this park!</Description><ExternalId>PF317851</ExternalId><ImageUrl/>
     <Name>Playground</Name>
</Product>
<Product>
<Description>Have a great time at this park!</Description><ExternalId>PF317851</ExternalId><ImageUrl/>
     <Name>Playground</Name>
</Product>
     </Products>
     </Feed>
```

`<str name="body">` should be treated as description, `<int name="is_park_id">` should be treated as `<ExternalId>` and `<str name="title">` should be treated as `<Name>`.

Could you help in formatting the XML to new format?

Comment: xsl might be a better bet for you than straight perl. What have you tried thus far?

Comment: I have tried XML::Simple, but unable to acheive required format as I feel the XML is complicated having more tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the XML::SAX/XML::Simple version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
package XML::SAX::Handler::Parks;
use strict;
use warnings qw(all);

use base qw(XML::SAX::Base);

sub new {
    return bless {
        data    => '',
        from_to => {
            body                => 'Description',
            is_park_id          => 'ExternalId',
            ss_image_thumb_small=> 'ImageUrl',
            title               => 'Name',
        },
        product => {},
        products=> [],
        this    => '',
    } => __PACKAGE__;
}

sub start_element {
    my ($self, $el) = @_;
    $self->{data} = '';
    if ($el->{Name} =~ /^(?:int|str)$/x) {
        while (my (undef, $attr) = each %{$el->{Attributes}}) {
            if ($attr->{Name} eq 'name') {
                $self->{this} = $attr->{Value};
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

sub end_element {
    my ($self, $el) = @_;
    my $key = $self->{from_to}{$self->{this}};
    $self->{product}{$key} = $self->{data};
    if ($el->{Name} eq 'doc') {
        push @{$self->{products}}, { %{$self->{product}} };
        $self->{product} = {};
    }
    return;
}

sub characters {
    my ($self, $data) = @_;
    $self->{data} .= $data->{Data};
    return;
}

1;

package main;
use strict;
use warnings qw(all);

use XML::Simple;
use XML::SAX::PurePerl;

my $handler = XML::SAX::Handler::Parks->new;
my $parser = XML::SAX::PurePerl->new(Handler => $handler);

$parser->parse_file(\*DATA);

print XMLout(
    {
        Products => {
            Product => $handler->{products},
        },
    },
    KeyAttr     => [],
    NoAttr      => 1,
    RootName    => 'Feed',
    XMLDecl     => 1,
);

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <result name="response" numFound="58582" start="0">
    <doc>
      <str name="body">Have a great time at this park!</str>
      <int name="is_park_id">317851</int>
      <str name="ss_image_thumb_small"/>
      <str name="title">Playground</str>
    </doc>
    <doc>
      <str name="body">hello world</str>
      <int name="is_park_id">12345</int>
      <str name="ss_image_thumb_small"/>
      <str name="title">Park</str>
    </doc>
  </result>
</response>
```

Comment: one more help, I have tested for a list of doc and it resulted in output of the product for the last one only. could you let me know how to pass array of doc to the handler

Comment: Oh, sorry, I assumed that your input XML holds one register per document. Could you please edit your question to provide a multi-register document?

Comment: I have made the change to the question, many thanks creaktive.

Comment: Hi creaktive, could you provide the code for multi-register document as discussed. Thanks again.

Comment: OK, it's multi-register document now :)

Comment: Warning:: Use of uninitialized value in hash element at this line(and I see output of only 1 doc record) $self->{product}{$key} = $self->{data};

Answer (score 1):

I just tried XML::Simple on your file. Here's my program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml_ref = XMLin("test.xml");

say Dumper $xml_ref;
```

Here's the output:

```
VAR1 = {
          'result' => {
                      'name' => 'response',
                      'doc' => {
                               'int' => {
                                        'content' => '317851',
                                        'name' => 'is_park_id'
                                      },
                               'str' => {
                                        'body' => {
                                                  'content' => 'Have a great time at this park!'
                                                },
                                        'ss_image_thumb_small' => {},
                                        'title' => {
                                                   'content' => 'Playground'
                                                 }
                                      }
                             },
                      'numFound' => '58582',
                      'start' => '0'
                    }
        };
```

It parses your XML file perfectly.

Do you understand Perl references and how you can hashes of hashes in Perl? That may be your issue.

Comment: I guess he/she is having troubles walking nested Perl structures.

Comment: Thanks David. I am having trouble in writing this perl structure to the required output  format. Could you help in writing the dumper result response to the required output format?

Comment: So, you don't know about Perl references and how they're used? That's a bit long to do as a single StackOverflow answer. Fortunately, Perl has a [Tutorial on References](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html). Take a look at that to learn how to parse though hashes of hashes, etc. Also look at the [ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) command. This helps you see what type of structure a reference is pointing to.

Comment: Thanks David, I will go through them. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings qw(all);

use Data::DPath qw(dpath);
use File::Slurp;
use XML::Hash::LX;

# parse XML and store as a nested Perl hash
my $xml = xml2hash(read_file('input.xml'));

# from/to key mapping
my $from_to = {
    body                => 'Description',
    is_park_id          => 'ExternalId',
    ss_image_thumb_small=> 'ImageUrl',
    title               => 'Name',
};

# translate one bucket
my %result =
    map {
        $from_to->{$_} => (
            $xml ~~
            dpath qq(//*[key eq "-name" and value eq "$_"]/../#text)
        )->[0] // ''
    } keys %$from_to;

# output new XML
say hash2xml({
    Feed => {
        Products => {
            Product => \%result,
        },
    },
});
```

Using XPath would be more appropriate, though.

Comment: Thanks creaktive. I don't have required libraries(XML::Hash::LX and Data::DPath), I should have mentioned earlier, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Which XML-related modules are available to you? Try running `perl -MExtUtils::Installed -E 'say for grep /\bxml\b/i, ExtUtils::Installed->new->modules'` to see every local module with "xml" in it's name.

Comment: I am trying to run that command and I have this response "Unrecognized switch: -E  (-h will show valid options)."

Comment: Try this one: `perl -MExtUtils::Installed -e 'print "$_\n" for grep /\bxml\b/i, ExtUtils::Installed->new->modules`. It seems that you have Perl prior to v5.10.

Comment: Thanks creaktive, this time it worked            XML::NamespaceSupport
XML::Parser
XML::RegExp
XML::SAX
XML::Simple

Comment: Please tell me if you understand the following XML::SAX based translator: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13744722/1818793 If not, I could adapt it for your need.

Comment: please adapt to my need(as I am a newbie to PERL), Many Thanks creaktive

Answer (score 0):

I use XML::LibXML for all my XML needs in perl.

```
use XML::LibXML;

my @records;

# parse input

{
    my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => 'input.xml' );

    my $root_node = $dom->documentElement;  # <response> tag

    for my $doc_node ( $root_node->getChildrenByTagName('doc') ) {

        my $record = {};    

        for my $node ( $doc_node->childNodes ) {
            $record{name} = $node->getAttribute('name');
            $record{value} = $node->textContent;
        }

        push @records, $record;
    }
}

# create output

{
    my $dom = XML::LibXML::Document->new('1.0',$some_encoding);

    my $root_node = $doc->createElement('Feed');

    my $products_node = $root_node->createElement('Products');

    for my $record ( @records ) {

        my $pnode = $products_node->createElement('Product');

        my $dnode = $pnode->createElement('Description');

        $dnode->appendText( $record->{body} );

        my $nnode = $pnode->createElement('Name');

        $nnode->appendText( $record->{name} );

        # ...

    }


    print $dom->toString;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to test in other server which has XML::LibXML, my perl script is aborted due to below compilation errors                "Global symbol "%record" requires explicit package name " in $record{name} and $record{value}

Comment: My apologies, I didn't run this code before posting it. This is because $record is a HashReference, not a Hash. So it should have been $record->{name} - the -> operator de-references the variable so you can access the hash. I recommend following David W. advice and learning about references and how they are used. They are very fundamental to programming in perl, and you will encounter many roadblocks without a firm grasp on the concept. When asking for questions regarding perl programming, many people will assume that you already have this topic under your belt.